# nginx subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, config

Ok I can't seem to get it, I've checked nginx forum, not much help there either.  I thought this would be simple.  I want defined subdomains to go to a different url/port.  i.e.

```
DNS site.com goes to 192.168.1.1 w/ masking
DNS www.site.com goes 192.168.1.1 w/ masking
DNS red.site.com goes 192.168.1.1 w/ masking
DNS blue.site.com goes to 192.168.1.1 w/ masking
```

I want site.com and www.site.com to function as normal, but I want red.site.com to go to 192.168.1.2:5000 and blue.site.com to go to 192.168.1.2:6000/temp/

etc, etc....I'm not even sure I care what displays in the address bar, I guess it would be nice if it stayed red.site.com, but it's not important.  I've tried a proxy pass a url rewrite, clearly I am doing something wrong.  Is this even possible?

Comment: nginx at what port is listening? is it a proxy of others services?

Comment: nginx is listening on port 80

Comment: what listens to port 6000 and 5000? explain a little more what is the setup.

Comment: i have a few webservices that run on different ports 5000 and 6000 were just examples. for example one port is running my xbmc remote web service.

Comment: was also considering forwarding something like ftp/ssh to my ftp/ssh port etc

Comment: seems more reliable to me, in order to forward non http protocol, use firewall rules

Comment: why don't you map directly red and blue domains to the correct machine? in this way you can call the services using red.site.com:5000 and blue.site.com:6000/temp/, is there some reason for using nginx?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [Proxy pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) directive?

With something like

```
server {
  server_name red.site.com;

  location  / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:5000;
  }
}
server {
  server_name blue.site.com;

  location  / {
    proxy_pass 192.168.1.2:6000/temp/;
  }
}
```

should work. Look at the documentation for things like header to forward etc...

Comment: When i try the proxy pass, i just end up getting the default "welcome to nginx" page, i don't get any erros about the config when starting it though, its almost like it doesnt interpret it at all...

Answer (score 3):

Create as many virtual servers as you need. Check in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and copy the `default` server to `red` ... (or where your config here). Then go to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and do a symlink

```
ln -s ../sites-available/red
```

and do the same for other servers (*blue*...), then restart *nginx* or `killall -HUP nginx` to reload the config.

Basically in a virtual server you give whatever configuration is specific to that server.

For instance, for `red`

```
server {
  listen 5000;
  server_name red.site.com;
  root /var/www/docs/red;
  ...
}
```

or for `blue` (notice the `temp` added to *root*)

```
server {
  listen 6000;
  server_name blue.site.com;
  root /var/www/docs/somewhere/temp;
  ...
}
```

If you need to specify the IP as well, do

```
  listen 192.168.1.2:5000;
```

for `red`, or 6000 for `blue`.

Some [litterature](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule) that explains the directives.

Answer (score 3):

You should create the file, if it not exists:

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/servers.conf

And fill it with a proxy settings. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name red.site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }
}
```